# MVC 3 JQuery UI autocomplete use model collection instead of action json result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

In my app I use auto complete text boxes. The problem is that for their source I have an action that returns me the items as JSON. Since I got only few items I do not want to call  every time after the user press a key. I have the items in my model. How can I generate the JSON array from my model?

Something like: @Model.Categories.ToJsonAray(c=>c.Name)
It is also good if you can tell me how to generate the json array from a list of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Categories.Select(x => c.Name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

```
@{var myJson =new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Categories.Select(c=>c.Name));}
@myJson
```

Comment: source: @{ new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Designers.Select(c => c.Text)); },       not working :(

Comment: Do you get an exception? Could you provide more details on how it is not working?

Comment: I get no exception ... but the output in empty in my view :( I enclosed the constructor in @{ ... ;}. Is this wrong?